# How do I change Magento store when making API (SOAP) call?

Tags: api, magento, soap

I need to create orders through the API with some special settings. So I have created a second store for API calls. But for whatever reason the API only communicates with the first store.

Ive changed the API-store to be the default with no effect.

How do I change the store when making API calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set current store by api call by calling using method catalogCategoryCurrentStore($sessionId, '1');

For more details visit http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.currentStore.html and look how they are setting the store.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryCurrentStore($sessionId, '1');
var_dump($result);
```

change the details as per your host & user.